# Remove Windows PowerShell transcript start header

Tags: powershell

When using the below to setup logging:

```
$ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
Stop-Transcript | out-null
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
Start-Transcript -path C:\output.txt
```

The below header is always added - is there any way to stop this being added?

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20130413235532
Username  : computer\administrator 
Machine   : wsa (Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0) 
**********************
Transcript started, output file is C:\output.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to prevent `Start-Transcript` from outputting those headers.  Also keep in mind that Start-Transcript doesn't log output of EXEs.  If you need to log script output and are on PowerShell v3, your best bet is to do it like this:

```
PS> .\myscript.ps1 *> myscript.log
```

This will log everything except `Write-Host` output.